# twilio phoneNUmber pricing api throw exception

Tags: java, twilio

[https://pricing.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/Countries/{countryCode}](https://pricing.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/Countries/%7BcountryCode%7D)

API is fetching country and give a response like

expected response =>

```
{
    "url": "https://pricing.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/Countries/US",
    "country": "United States",
    "price_unit": "USD",
    "phone_number_prices": [
        {
            "number_type": "local",
            "base_price": "1.00",
            "current_price": "1.00"
        },
        {
            "number_type": "toll free",
            "base_price": "2.00",
            "current_price": "2.00"
        }
    ],
    "iso_country": "US"
}
```

but I am facing a problem while fetching country, it will give exception

```
Country country= Country.fetcher(countryCode).fetch();
```

exception =>

```
Unrecognized field "number_type" (class com.twilio.type.PhoneNumberPrice), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "basePrice", "type", "base_price", "currentPrice", "current_price"])
 at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 212] (through reference chain: com.twilio.rest.pricing.v1.phonenumber.Country["phone_number_prices"]-
>java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.twilio.type.PhoneNumberPrice["number_type"])
```

how to resolve this problem

Comment: how is the error not clear? Unrecognized field "number_type" (class com.twilio.type.PhoneNumberPrice), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "basePrice", "type", "base_price", "currentPrice", "current_price"])  it lists exactly what fields you can have, and number_type isn't one of them. change number_type to type.
Also, why is there both a currentPrice and current_price?

Comment: private final double basePrice;
    private final double currentPrice;
    private final Type type;
 I have three properties in my PhoneNumberPrice class

Comment: you may want to start with reading your error messages.

Comment: seriously: read the error message: it tells you in detail what is wrong. In the json, you have type number_type, you don't have that in your class. so, change your json from number_type to type, or try and parse it to the correct class.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

What version of the Twilio Java library are you using? This looks like [an issue that was fixed back in March 2017](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/pull/333).

I recommend you upgrade the version of the Twilio Java library you are using and if that doesn't solve the issue, raise [an issue on the library repo](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/issues).